# How to split 123abcd@abcd.com like 123 and abcd@abcd.com in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have like a bunch of texts in a txt file like that.

I just want to split the starting numbers and email separately like above

Can someone make a function or something for that alone please? will be very thankful.

Any other suggestion is also gladly welcome. !

Answer (score 4):

You could try the below code.

```
<?php
$yourstring = "123abcd@abcd.com";
$regex = '~^\d+\K~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $yourstring);
print_r($splits);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => abcd@abcd.com
)
```

Explanation:

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits.
- `\K` discards the previously matched characters. So after `^\d+\K`, the matching marker would be on the boundary exists between the starting number and the email id. Splitting according to that boundary will give you the desired result.